# If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\frac{x^2}{2} < 2$ then $\exists a \in \mathbb{Q}$, $a>0$ where $\frac{x^2}{2}<a^2<2$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, rational-numbers

There is this demonstration in my calculus book that I can't understand:

I want to prove that:

If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\frac{x^2}{2} < 2$ then $\exists a \in \mathbb{Q}$,  $a>0$ where $\frac{x^2}{2}<a^2<2$.

**Dem:**

If $\frac{x^2}{2} \leq 1$ then $a = \frac{11}{10}$ satisfies the proposition.

If $y = \frac{x^2}{2} >1$, let's take an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ where

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^2<y$ and $(1+\frac{1}{n})^2 <\frac{2}{y} $

We can find this $n$, just see that
 $(1+\frac{1}{n})^2 = 1 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1 + \frac{3}{n} $

If we take an $n$ where $1+\frac{3}{n} < y^* \implies n>\frac{3}{y^*-1}$ with $y^* = min\{y,\frac{2}{y}\}$ then $(1+\frac{1}{n})^2 = 1 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1 + \frac{3}{n} $.

If $u = 1+\frac{1}{n}$ where $n>\frac{3}{y^*-1}$. Then there will be a term $v$ in the progression $u^2, u^4, u^6,...,u^{2k},...$
where $\frac{x^2}{2} < v <2$

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ where $\frac{x^2}{2}<u^{2m}<2$ then $ a = u^k$

---

Here are my questions:

**Question 1:**

How we can prove the inequality
$(1+\frac{1}{n})^2 = 1 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1 + \frac{3}{n} $

I tried to use induction, but it did not work for me.

*Solution:* $\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n} \implies 1 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1 + \frac{3}{n} $

**Question 2:**

Why if $u = 1+\frac{1}{n}$ where $n>\frac{3}{y^*-1}$. Then there will be a term $v$ in the progression $u^2, u^4, u^6,...,u^{2k},...$
where $\frac{x^2}{2} < v <2$.

Comment: $1/n^2\le 1/n$.

Comment: Thanks! This really answer my first question... I can't believe i could not see this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Question 2**:

The idea is that $u^2,u^4,u^6,\ldots$ is a geometric progression with ratio $r$ greater than $1$ and with:
$$r=u^2= \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^2 < \frac{2}{y}=\frac{2}{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
and with initial term:
$$u^2 < y=\frac{x^2}{2}$$

---

To prove it let us suppose that there is not $k$ such that $u^{2k} \in (x^2/2,2)$.

As $u^2 <x^2/2$ and $(u^{2k})$ is an increasing sequence going to $+\infty$ (as the ration is $>1$) there exists $k_0$ such that:

$$u^{2k_0} \leq \frac{x^2}{2} < 2 \leq u^{2(k_0+1)}  $$
so:
$$\frac{u^{2(k_0+1)}}{u^{2k_0}} \geq \frac{2}{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
i.e:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^2 \geq \frac{2}{y}$$
which is in contradiction with the choice of $n$.